# How to make a knot animation

Tags: animation

I'm doing knot animations in Blender using "Spline"
This works well if a knot is tied when you need to pull on its edges, but some knots are tied when you need to pull on the middle of the rope. Can you please tell me,
with which I can animate such a knot on image

[image: An example of a node that I need to animate]

[image: An example of a node that I know how to do]

The knot that I want to make in the first picture, the knot that I know how to make in the second picture

Comment: The knot that I want to make in the first picture, the knot that I know how to make in the second picture

Comment: How did you make the knot in the second picture? And why does it not work for the first image?

Comment: I'm doing knot animations in Blender using "Spline", but at first image, I need to pull on the middle of the rope, and I don't known how it make using "Spline" - sorry my English is bad :)